# Unexpectedly found nil IBOutlet in prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a detail view controller, and I would like to set the label text to a value taken from an array using an indexPath row.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "showView"){
        let detailVC: DetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
        let indexPath = self.MainTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        detailVC.label.text = "Test"
        self.MainTableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        }
}
```

I keep getting a fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value. I have tried switching `detailVC.label.text = "Test"` to `detailVC.label.text = names[indexPath.row]` but I keep getting the same error every time.

I used the same lines of code for changing the cell's label text, with no errors, but for this label in the center of a blank view I cannot seem to get it right? Any thoughts on what needs to be changed?

By the way, the label in the detail view controller is     `@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!`

Comment: Have you tried adding a property to the destination view controller and assigning it the value of the text and just assigning the label the text in the viewDidLoad or viewWIllAppear?

Comment: where are you getting the unexpectedly found nil error?

Comment: @AlessandroOrrù in the console

Comment: @MikeSchmidt, see vadian's answer below

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot access `IBOutlet`s of `DetailViewController` in `prepareForSegue` because they are not connected yet.

As mentioned in the comments create a `String` property in `DetailViewController`, set it in `prepareForSegue` and set the `text` property of the label in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` of `DetailViewController`.

Answer (score 3):

The alternative is to call `detailVC.loadViewIfNeeded()` before setting the property. It will load all your `IBOutlet`'s